# How to get data from PHP to mysqli via POST?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to this, but I need help to see where I've gone wrong. This is the code which I have tried:

```
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="lastname" type="text" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Details</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="details" type="text" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is the PHP page for processing and inputting into the database:

```
<?php

$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$lastname=$_REQUEST['lastname'];
$details=$_REQUEST['details'];

//connect to Database
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "name", "pass", "DB");

//check connection
if (!$Link){
    printf("Connect Failed: %s/n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
//turn auto commit off
mysqli_autocommit($link,FALSE);

mysqli_query ($link,"INSERT INTO IncidentDatabase (First_Name, Last_Name,Inciden_Details) VALUES ('$name','$lastname','$details')");

/* commit transaction */
mysqli_commit($link);

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: "thats the end of the question" — Where is the start of the question? You have shown us some code, but you haven't said what it is supposed to do or what it does.

Comment: are you trying to use prepared statement?

Comment: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Im trying to get the information from the form into the DB and it keeps telling me there is a connection error, I can't see th eproblem

Comment: that's not a form it's a table. try using the `<form>` tag. instead of `$_REQUEST` use `$_POST`. Change `!$Link` to `!$link`. Double check spelling, e.g. `Inciden_Details` = `Incident_Details` ??

Comment: You are using both "Link" and "link" for the same variable. Fix it first. And concatenate your variables with dots on your query, don't write them straight into the string.

Comment: i think you have missed some code

Comment: have you changed username and password of phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: xkcd]
> xkcd

It looks like you're trying to mix object-oriented and procedural styles. Either you need to replace `new mysqli` with `mysqli_connect`, or use `$link->something()` functions instead. I don't believe you can mix and match.

In addition, you should use `$_POST` (or `$_GET`, depending on the form's method) instead of `$_REQUEST` to ensure you're getting stuff from the right place.

As for your connection error, `$link` and `$Link` are two different variables. Variable names are case-sensetive.

Comment: Cheers Mate appreciate the help

Comment: That was it, It worked. thank you for helping me do something I,ve been trying to do for over a week and a Half.